# Getting Focused Browser Tabs in OSX

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to get active browser tab from browsers. I can do that for Chrome with this code:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set myURL to the URL of the active tab of the front window
end tell
```

For Safari, I am changing Chrome to Safari but it is not working at all

Is there anyone to help me about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Safari** it's:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set myURL to the URL of the current tab of the front window
end tell
```

You also do not need to be so verbose, dropping all occurrences of `the`, e.g.:

```
set myURL to URL of current tab of front window
```

Does the same thing.

In **Script Editor**, look in the **Library** for **Safari**:

- **Script Editor** > **Window** > **Library** > **Safari**

[image]

Comment: Thx man.. i got the answer myseld after posted the question.. I ll share myself now.


set myBrowser to "Safari"
if "Safari" is in myBrowser then
 tell application "Safari" to return URL of front document as string
else if "Google Chrome" is in myBrowser then
 tell application "Google Chrome"
  set myBrowser to the URL of the active tab of the front window
 end tell
end if

Comment: Sorry i couldn t find how to show l code layout in my previous comment. :(

Answer (score 1):

This code finds Gmail tab among all windows and all tabs and makes focus to it.

```
set tabTitle to "Gmail"
tell application "Google Chrome"
    
    activate
    repeat with w in (windows)
        set tabIndex to 0
        repeat with t in (tabs of w)
            set tabIndex to tabIndex + 1
            if title of t contains tabTitle then
                set (active tab index of w) to tabIndex
                set index of w to 1
                return
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This is the answer i tried.. @user3439894